# Optimize Pandas filtering does not working

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using python pandas. I am looking for a way to make the condition below   much faster. I have 1 millions of data and it takes a lot of times

Here is a sample of dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'LARG': pd.Categorical(['HSDm','HSeDm','HSDsd','KLKL','jlk','KLKL','HSDm','GOJ','LO','GOJ','LO']),
                    'Combine_Model_Variant_Version': pd.Categorical(['01SAF1d','01SAF1f','01SzF1d','0ISAF1d','0ISAF1E','0ISAF1EM','0ISAF1EM','01SAF1d','92SAF1d','01S65Ad','01MF1d'])
                    })
df
```

Combine_MVV is a string of a list containing many LARG elements

```
df.loc[df.Combine_Model_Variant_Version==Combine_MVV,'LARG'].values[0].strip()
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you post a sample of data?

Comment: You’re only getting the first element of that filtered series, is that correct ? Can you give examples of what these `LARG` and `Combine_Model_Variant_Version` columns contain ? Maybe a `df.sample(100)` or something like that ?

Comment: @crayxt I have posted a sample

Comment: @Cimbali Yes I am getting always the first element. I have posted a sample

Comment: @hko What is `Combine_MVV`?

Comment: @crayxt Combine_MVV is a string of a list containing many LARG elements

Comment: Can you update your post with `Combine_MVV` value please?